# Forms not displaying correctly when integrating AdminLTE template into Symfony

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, twig, symfony, adminlte

I used the CRUD generator for my entities, then I integrated a template AdminLTE; it works; now I tried to set the display of my twig file I start with the `new.html.twig` file (form) I want it follows the layout of the base template

<kbd>new.html.twig</kbd>

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block body  %}
    <h1>User creation</h1>

    {{ form_start(form) }}
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    {{ form_end(form) }}

    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="{{ path('user_index') }}">Back to the list</a>
        </li>
    </ul>   
{% endblock %}
```

<kbd>index.html.twig</kbd>

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block body  %}    
    <h1>User list</h1>

    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Lastname</th>
                <th>Gender</th>
                <th>Birthday</th>
                <th>Birthplace</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Phonenumber</th>
                <th>Grade</th>
                <th>Profile</th>
                <th>Documentid</th>
                <th>Photoid</th>
                <th>Directeur</th>
                <th>Codirecteur</th>
                <th>Effectue</th>
                <th>Mediaid</th>
                <th>Created</th>
                <th>Updated</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for user in users %}
            <tr>
                <td><a href="{{ path('user_show', { 'id': user.id }) }}">{{ user.id }}</a></td>
                <td>{{  user.name }}</td>
                <td>{{  user.lastName }}</td>
                <td>{{ user.gender }}</td>
                <td>{% if user.birthday %}{{ user.birthday|date('Y-m-d') }}{% endif %}</td>
                <td>{{ user.birthPlace }}</td>
                <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
                <td>{{ user.phoneNumber }}</td>
                <td>{{ user.grade }}</td>
                <td>{{ user.profile }}</td>
                <td>{{ user.documentId }}</td>
                <td>{{ user.photoId }}</td>
                <td>{% if user.directeur %}Yes{% else %}No{% endif %}</td>
                <td>{% if user.coDirecteur %}Yes{% else %}No{% endif %}</td>
                <td>{% if user.effectue %}Yes{% else %}No{% endif %}</td>
                <td>{{ user.mediaId }}</td>
                <td>{% if user.created %}{{ user.created|date('Y-m-d H:i:s') }}{% endif %}</td>
                <td>{% if user.updated %}{{ user.updated|date('Y-m-d H:i:s') }}{% endif %}</td>
                <td>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="{{ path('user_show', { 'id': user.id }) }}">show</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="{{ path('user_edit', { 'id': user.id }) }}">edit</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="{{ path('user_new') }}">Create a new entry</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

<kbd>config.yml</kbd>

```
#Twig Configuration twig: 
debug: "%kernel.debug%"
strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"
form_themes: - user:new.html.twig
```

Before touching config.yml, I had it attached display:

[image]

Comment: Hey Amine, how did you integrate the AdminLte? by requiring it directly (`composer require "almasaeed2010/adminlte"`) or by the avanzu bundle (`composer require "avanzu/admin-theme-bundle"`)?

Answer (score 0):

*Your question is quite vague, but I think I see the issue.*

You want to integrate the AdminLTE template into Symfony3, you've already updated the `base.html.twig` (which all other templates will extend) with the required HTML & CSS, but your form elements are not displaying correctly (looking at the provided screenshot).

We can instruct Symfony to render all forms with bootstrap styling by default using one of the following methods.

---

### Application Wide

This will render **all twig forms** with bootstrap classes applied.

Update your `app/config/config.yml` to include the following.

```
# app/config/config.yml
twig:
    form:
        # All forms will use the `vertical` bootstrap form layout
        resources: ['bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig']

        # All forms will use the `horizontal` layout
        # resources: ['bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout.html.twig']
```

---

### Form Specific

We can apply a style to a **single twig form** using the following.
Note the `form_theme` tag which accepts the `form` and the form theme.

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block body  %}
    <h1>User creation form</h1>

    {# {% form_theme form 'bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout.html.twig' %} #}

    {% form_theme form 'bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig' %}
    {{ form_start(form) }}
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    {{ form_end(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

---

[image: AdminLTE Symfony Bootstrap Form Integration]

---

> The Symfony docs covers form customization in more detail.
>
> - [Symfony Docs: How to Customize Form Rendering](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html)
>   http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html
> - View the default themes provided by Symfony on Github.
>   https://github.com/symfony/symfony/tree/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form